# Marginal density of Y in joint density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image: Question]

I found marginal density of $Y$ to be $4y$ after integrating 8xy within limits 1 and 0, with respect to $x$, to get $4y$. However, the solution pack is telling me that the marginal density of Y is the below:
[image: marginal density of y]

Here is my working to get $4y$ as marginal density of $Y$:

[image: my marginal density working for Y]
I don't understand how also $0<y<1$, when it should be $0<y<x$?

Comment: Start by drawing a picture for yourself of the region $0 < y < x < 1$. Also double check that any marginal you end up with integrates to unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of the joint distribution is the triangle determined by $x=1$, $y=1$, and $y=x$. Therefore, to find $f_Y(y)$ you need to move in parallel to the x-axis at some $Y=y$ so
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{y}^{1}8xy\, dx = 4y(1-y^2)$$
as in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how also $0<y<1~$, when it should be $0<y<x~$ ?

There is no variable $x$ in $f_Y(y)$, so how can it be used as the upper bound for its support ?

---

You wish to evaluate $f_Y(y)$ by integrating $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ over its support of $0<y<x<1$.

So this integration must be over $x\in(y~,1)$.

After doing this, there will be no variable $x$ to restrict the support for $f_Y$, so the upper bound must be $1$.

Thus it shall be supported over $y\in(0~,1)$  .

$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \begin{cases}\displaystyle 8y\int_y^1 x\,\mathrm d x&:& 0<y<1\\[1ex] 0&:& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\\[2ex]&=\begin{cases}4y(1-y^2)&:& 0<y<1\\[1ex] 0&:& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\end{align}$$